# Integral with increasing function

Tags: calculus, integration, monotone-functions

I have the following problem: Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f'(t) \geq 0$, $f(0)=0$ and define the function

\begin{align}
\chi_c(t) := \begin{cases}
t & \text{if } |t| \leq c\\
\text{sgn}(t)c& \text{if } |t| > c.
\end{cases},\quad c > 0.
\end{align}

I want to show that for $x:[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $T>0$ and any $t \in [0,T]$ it holds

\begin{align}
\int_0^t f(x(s)) \chi_c(x'(s)) ds \geq  \color{red}{-C(x(0), f, c)},
\end{align}

where $C(x(0), f, c)>0$ is a constant depending only on $x(0)$, $f$ and $c$.

My idea:

If we ignore the cutoff function $\chi_c$ for a moment, we have

\begin{align}
\int_0^t f(x(\tau)) x'(\tau) d\tau = \int_0^t \frac{d}{d\tau} \int_0^{x(\tau)} f(s)dsd\tau = \int_0^{x(t)} f(s)ds \color{red}{ - \int_0^{x(0)} f(s)ds \geq - \int_0^{x(0)} f(s)ds}.
\end{align}

But in the case including $\chi_c$ I'm stuck, even though I think it should not change too much. Does anybody have an idea? Thank you in advance.